# Sudo confirmation prompt

Tags: linux, sudo

I use sudo on my linux workstation, and it is configured to request a password each time.

But typing the password every time is cumbersome and also a bit dangerous if I don't have the focus to the right window.

I'd like to configure sudo to have the following behaviour:

- If headless (no X11), request full password
- If X11 is available prompt for confirmation, the confirmation should be a gui window with an allow and deny button and some simple input (like type yes to confirm, to prevent hitting enter accidentally)

Comment: I did not mention it, but if you have an idea that use some hardware (like fingerprint reader), that would work too. In the end I just want to grant sudo rapidly.

Answer (score 3):

It's technically possible with `sudo -A`. From [`man 8 sudo`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.3/sudo.man.html):

> `-A`
>   Normally, if `sudo` requires a password, it will read it from the user's terminal. If the `-A` (askpass) option is specified, a (possibly graphical) helper program is executed to read the user's password and output the password to the standard output. If the `SUDO_ASKPASS` environment variable is set, it specifies the path to the helper program. […]

Your solution may look like this:

1. Write a helper script. The script should check if X11 is available.

   - If it is, the script should display a window you desire. If you allow, the script will read your password from a file and print to standard output (`cat file` may be enough).
   - If X11 is not available, the script should use stdin (e.g. `read -rs` in Bash) to get the password from you; then print it to standard output.

   Securing the file (so nobody else can read it) and the script (so nobody else can change it) is your concern now.
2. Set `SUDO_ASKPASS="/path/to/your/helper/script"` and export it.
3. Define an alias `alias sudo='sudo -A'`.

Note the answer only states this is technically possible. It doesn't say this is secure or recommended.

Comment: Well, the idea is that even my user shouldn't be able to escalate to root without graphical confirmation. With this setup, the password file would be readable by my user.

Comment: @NicolasGoy I don't follow. You know your password in the first place, so what difference does the readable file make?

Comment: Because if I run a malicious script it could read the file and run as root without me knowing. But well, that's very unlikely as it would have to know in which file I store my password. I'm against security through obscurity, but I guess it wouldn't be a problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally more dangerous as this makes local privilege escalation very easy. Perhaps you can achieve close to intended results by compiling polkit with a timeout which suits your needs? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409636/pkexec-how-do-i-set-a-custom-timeout-for-auth-admin-keep-when-writting-a-pkexe

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you [edit] your answer to include the relevant information from the link, by way of explanation? Thanks